# How i can cancel an alarm after a period of time? | android

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms

hi  i have an alarm here and i want a way to cancel it AFTER a period of time like a day for example or a week ,,, and thanks in advance ,,

```
    am = (AlarmManager)parent.getContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

     //the title and the description of the notification



    Intent alarmintent = new Intent(parent.getContext(), Alarm_Receiver.class);
     alarmintent.putExtra("title",titlePills + dea22);
      alarmintent.putExtra("note",dea22);
     alarmintent.putExtra("NOTIFICATION_ID",String.valueOf(CountMultipleAlarm));
     //HELLO_ID is a static variable that must be initialized at the BEGINNING OF CLASS with 1;

      //example:protected static int HELLO_ID =1;
      PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(parent.getContext(), CountMultipleAlarm,
                                     alarmintent,0);

      //VERY IMPORTANT TO SET FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT... this will send correct extra's informations to 
       //AlarmReceiver Class
         // Get the AlarmManager service
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,cal.getTimeInMillis(), 11000, sender);
                                     intentArray.add(sender);
```

Comment: Set another alarm that's purpose is to cancel the original alarm?

Comment: please do you have a code ? i don't know how i do the cancel function with a period time

Comment: My answer shows the code you need to put in your cancel alarm receiver. You've already set up an alarm, I'm going to assume you can set up a second, just plot the code I included in there (Might need a few extra bits you already have lying around), and you should be good to go.

Comment: i mean the cancel function only take one argument how i should put in the alarm object that i want to cancel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have already set an alarm once, so you know how to do it. The key is to set a second alarm, whose purpose is to end the original alarm. The difficult part is finding the original alarm to cancel, however, you can just execute this code upon your second alarm to cancel the first, using the [cancel pending intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#cancel%28android.app.PendingIntent%29). This code, as Android docs specify, will cancel all alarms with the same class. Thus, you only need to create an intent, pass it to the AlarmManager, and you can cancel the alarm.

```
Intent alarmintent = new Intent(parent.getContext(), Alarm_Receiver.class);
PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(parent.getContext(), CountMultipleAlarm,
                                 alarmintent,0);
am.cancel(sender);
```

Comment: Is "parent.getContext()" above the same as the "CurrentActivity.this"  What would I do if the original Intent, PendingIntent and AlarmManager were all used in a different Activity than CurrentActivity to create the alarm?  How do I cancel the original alarm from another Activity in the CurrentActivity?

Answer (score 1):

Set a second alarm that cancels the first alarm.

Comment: please do you have a code ? i don't know how i do the cancel function with a period time

Answer (score 1):

try

```
final PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(parent.getContext(), CountMultipleAlarm,
                                     alarmintent,0);
int someTime=1000;

new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable()
{
    public void run()
    {
     am.cancel(sender);
    }
}, someTime);
```

Comment: with your solution the application has to run the whole time. Better to start a second alarm