# Sending in App Notification daily at Specific Time

Tags: android

I'm developing an android app in which i want to send notification daily at 14:30. I am able to get notification on time, But my problem is that, whenever i open app after 14:30, i received notification everytime. How to solve that ?
Code to send notification is here ... !

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 14);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);

Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TimeAlarm.class);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 100,intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
```

and code of **TimeAlarm.class** is ....

```
NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager)  context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

Intent repeating_intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);

repeating_intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 100, repeating_intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_btn_speak_now)
            .setContentTitle("Title")
            .setContentText("Text")
            .setAutoCancel(true);

manager.notify(100,builder.build());
```

Comment: `NotificationManager.cancelAll()` or `NotificationManager.cancel(notificationId)`

Comment: where to implement that ??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20635789/9025311

Comment: Its not working at all ..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_btn_speak_now)
            .setContentTitle("Title")
            .setContentText("Text")
            .setOngoing(false)
            .setWhen(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
            .setAutoCancel(true);

manager.notify(100,builder.build());
```

[setWhen](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setWhen(long))

```
NotificationCompat.Builder setWhen (long when)
```

Set the time that the event occurred. Notifications in the panel are sorted by this time.

You can even try [setShowWhen](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder)

Control whether the timestamp set with setWhen is shown in the content view.