# Can't schedule notification within FirebaseMessagingService

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I am trying to schedule a future notification using `AlarmManager` from `FirebaseMessagingService` when `onMessageReceived()`.

Note: `onMessageReceived()` gets triggered, and the same code works within an activity, but not within the service.

```
private void setReminder() {
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, ReminderReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent broadcast = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 5);

    alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), broadcast);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: take a look at this see if this helps you https://stackoverflow.com/a/50386399/9025311

Comment: The notification shows correctly when calling the function from an activity, but not from the service

Comment: what do you mean not from the service

Comment: Same code (the method), when called from a running activity gives the expected result. When called within the `onMessageReceived()` of `FirebaseMessagingService`, it doesn't work.

Comment: This is working as intended, notification messages are delivered to your onMessageReceived callback only when your app is in the foreground. If your app is in the background or closed then a notification message is shown in the notification center, and any data from that message is passed to the intent that is launched as a result of the user tapping on the notification.

Comment: another example https://stackoverflow.com/a/37471326/9025311

Comment: Thanks for the other link! My use case is this: - I send a notification with Firebase Functions on a certain trigger. - The notification gets displayed correctly. - After showing the notification, I want to schedule another one for a future time with AlarmManager

Comment: then you need to use the other link above

Comment: I appreciate your help!